# There is a missing link in the blog side panel of the questions page

Tags: bug, status-completed

On the questions page in the side panel for the blog this link

"How You Can Use the New Stack Overflow Bot from Microsoft"

leads to a page not found error

The link in question has now disappeared but it was shown here
[image: here]

Comment: could you maybe provide either a screenshot or even better the actual link?

Comment: The broken link isn't there anymore.

Comment: Then you might just have refreshed your page while the link was being removed?

Comment: It's working now.

Comment: thanks very much

Comment: I haven't done anything but you're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I saw it too -- a link to that SE blog post, and "page not found" if you followed it.  It's now fixed; that link goes to [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/25/can-use-new-stack-overflow-bot-microsoft/?cb=1).